# How do I convert this code to run in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, search, escaping

This doesn't work  in my code because I have a variable called HTML, which spits out all of the HTML.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  // to make :contains case insensitive!!!
  $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
    return function (elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

$('#filter').on('input', function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.val()) {
        $('.inventory tr').hide();
        $('.inventory').find('tr:Contains("' + $t.val() + '")').show();
    }
    else {
        $(".inventory tr").show();
    }
     $("#filter-count").text("Number of items = " + $(".inventory tr:visible").length);
});
});</script>
```

I heard \ escape was good, but where should I put them?

Answer (score 0):

easy. Just close PHP tag and then have this code as is

```
$foo = 'bar'; // whatever PHP code
?>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
  // to make :contains case insensitive!!!
  $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
    return function (elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
...
```